# How to send streamed json data as a key value pair into kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i write a jave code read a json data from local file system, and i want send that data as a key value pair's

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
        Stream<String> objec = Files.lines(Paths.get("path\\data.json"));


                String topicName="test";

                Properties props=new Properties();
                props.put("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
                props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");


                KafkaProducer<String,String> sampleProducer= new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);
                objec.forEach(f->{
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,f);        
                sampleProducer.send(record);
                });
                sampleProducer.close();
```

But when i run this program that will send a data to kafkaconsumer as a String, how could i send a json data as a key value pair to kafka consumer...

here the sample json file

```
{  
   "wifi_result":"1",
   "mic_result":"1",
   "video_result":"1",
   "touch_result":"1",
   "proximity_result":"1",
   "vibrator_result":"1",
   "power_key":"2",
   "accelerometer":"0",
   "earphone":"1",
   "memory_result":"1",
   "memory_internalSD":"1",
   "memory_internalSDSize":"25.0GB",
   "memory_externalSD":"0",
   "memory_externalSDSize":"",
   "memory_internalflash":"1",
   "memory_internalflashSize":"2.0GB",
   "vol_key_down":"0",
   "menu_key":"1",
   "headset_result":"1",

}
```

Help will be appreciate... Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are reading the file as string & not as json object. Secondly, if you can sample your data here with actual & expected data structure, it will give more insight to us to help you.

Comment: @AmithKumar no am reading a JSON file..

Comment: Yes I know you are reading a json file, but you are not parsing it as json object when reading inside java class but you are parsing it as string object. Please also post your expected topic record & actual topic record.

Comment: @AmithKumar I just want to read the data and post into some Kafka topic,But the data will be key value pair?? Not a string..!

Comment: Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: @AmithKumar nope I want stream the JSON data and send Kafka topic to key value pair..where key is located that will be stored in key column and value also same thing

Comment: I added the code updates to send json file data as kafka key value pair. Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: how to Write for this consumer with java api

Answer (score 2):

Read the json file as JSonObject instead of string, and then send it to Kafka topic. I am using gson library for parsing (as sample code) but you can choose any json parsing library of your choice.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {

    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static JsonObject readJSON(String filePath) throws Exception {
     JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filePath));
     return gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     String topicName = "test";

     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
     props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
     props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");


     KafkaProducer < String, String > sampleProducer = new KafkaProducer < String, String > (props);
     ProducerRecord < String, String > record = new ProducerRecord < String, String > (topicName, readJSON("data.json").toString());
     sampleProducer.send(record);
     sampleProducer.close();
    }
}
```

Also if just have to read the file & send it to topic as is, and not process any content. You can just read the whole file as String in one go & send it, rather than streaming line by line, this will preserve the json structure of the data:

```
    public static String readFileAsString(File file)
    throws IOException {
     InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
     int length = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
     fileInputStream.close();
     return new String(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    ProducerRecord < String, String > record = new ProducerRecord < String, String > (topicName, readFileAsString(new File("data.json")));
```

UPDATES:

To pass the json file data as key value to the Kafka topic, you still have to parse the file as json object & then stream through json properties. Please check sample code below, I parse the json file as Map object using Jacksons, and then stream through its properties to send to topic one by one.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

//read json file as map object
    private static Map<String, String> readJsonFileAsMap(File file) throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>(){});
    }

//stream data as key value pair
        KafkaProducer<String,String> sampleProducer= new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);
        readJsonFileAsMap(file).forEach((k,v)->{
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test",k,v);
            sampleProducer.send(record);
        });
        sampleProducer.close();
```

If you are using console consumer to verify the data make sure `print.key=true`, optionally you can add separator too `key.separator=:`

> kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning --property "print.key=true" -property "key.separator=:"